# How do I send two parameters with one link in Rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, model-view-controller, associations

I am working in a Rails evoting app.

I have the following models: User, Election, Contestant.

I want to allow multiple users vote for contestants in a particular election, and when the user has voted in that election the links to each users should be hidden.

This association is so complicated that I can't get it right.

These are my associations:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :contestants
  has_many :contestant_votes

end

class Contestant < ActiveRecord::Base
 mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
 belongs_to :user
 has_many :contestant_votes
 has_many :elections

 def votes
    read_attribute(:votes) || contestant_votes.sum(:value)
 end

end

class Election < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contestants
end
```

How do I hide the voting link if the current user has voted for a contestant in an election?

Comment: You can add a flag "voted" in User model to indicate if user already voted. and link hiding should be done in controller.

Comment: well, what if there is a new election? the voted filed will still remain false i suggest

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a uniqueness constraint on `contestant_votes`.  Then you can add a logic to check if there is a `contestant_vote` between the current user and the contestant.

Comment: Well, I do not fully understand what you ment can you please show me with some code example